# Do not get SQL Connection Exception when using EF5 Code First

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations, sqlconnection

Using EF5 Code First and Generic Repository/UOW pattern connecting to SQL Server 2008 R2 DB, When entering an invalid server entry in the connection string via app config, an invalid connection exception is not thrown - it runs through the model creating method and nothing happens, I was expecting an exception to be thrown which I can capture and return the information back to the user,

does anyone have any ideas why the exception is not being thrown.

I include code examples below

thanks in advance

Mark

BaseFootballContext which takes in the connection string (if I pass in an invalid string which points to a server I cannot connect to via Query Management Tool

```
public class BaseFootballContext : DbContext
{
    public BaseFootballContext(string nameOrConnectionString) : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
    }

    public IDbSet<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }
    // other IDbSets exist

    /// <summary>
    /// Set Primary Keys and other properties here using Fluent API
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="modelBuilder"></param>
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<Booking>()
                    .Property(x => x.Id)
                    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Booking>().HasKey(x => x.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Booking>().Property(x => x.Version).IsRowVersion();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Booking>().Ignore(x => x.IsBrief);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Booking>().Property(x => x.ModifiedDate).HasColumnType("datetime2");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Booking>().Property(x => x.CreatedDate).HasColumnType("datetime2");


    }
}
```

I have no exception handling higher up the chain, when debugging it goes into the model creating method and just carries on as normal, was expecting a connection exception to be thrown here.

Comment: This process does not try to hit the db. That doesn't happen until your first attempt to execute a query or command. I can't tell if that's also part of how your testing. Could that be the problem?

Comment: hi Julie, I thought at this point it would connect to the server and check if database is present if not then it would create database based on our model ?  We just want to capture if the connection is no good then an error is returned as we are providing a web front end with notification on a seperate service - so no real way of knowing what query or command would be hit first - if this is the case then may need to set a command which runs after this has been done to trigger an actual connection to the database which would return error if a user has entered an incorrect connection string.

Comment: nope. initialization happens the first time in the app process that the context tries to do something with the database. if you only want to check the connection, I wouldn't ask EF to do the intialization. You should use something more low-level like connection.open maybe.

Comment: done some more investigation, what actually happens is when I fire off a call to the Generic Repository, it triggers the call to the database this as you stated goes to the ModelCreating method, this runs but never comes back - no exception is thrown, this is what I am puzzled about, was expecting an exception to be bubbled up.

Comment: ok, so given that you are asking EF to hit the database, I would expect it.  Swallowing an exception somewhere? Next step will be walking through debug with you since I can't think of anything else and nobody else is offering up an idea. It's just not obvious to me. Sorry

Comment: ok - think we have cracked it, it does eventually throw an exception, done a test on the console app and exception is thrown, we had to change our web api data context timeout to greater than entity frameworks default of 30 secs so the client app would have time to receive the error rather than just issuing a timeout error.  Just got to check our notification part but we should be fine, thought it would be something stupid, you can mark your first comment as an answer as you pointed me in the right direction, many thanks

Answer (score 0):

(moving from comment) The process that Mark listed does not trigger database init or a call to the database. He then confirmed that he was executing a query on the context which would, indeed trigger a call to the database and should have thrown an exception to alert him to a problem with the connection string. So the question became one of hunting down the exception which was being "swallowed" by a timeout error. See details about this in the above comments.